# Display Nprogress on ajax = false

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, progress-bar

I am using [Nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) to display the progress of File upload. I am using primefaces File upload-

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{uploadCntrl.uploadedFile}" mode="simple"
                skinSimple="true" multiple="true" 
                update="ulmessage" />
<p:commandButton value="Upload"
                actionListener="#{uploadCntrl.uploadZip()}" ajax="false" 
                update="stat"
                onstart="NProgress.start();" onsuccess="NProgress.done();" />
```

The NProgress is working fine with ajax=true but the above p:commandButton requires ajax=false.
How to **make NProgress bar work with ajax=false?**

Also, are there **any alternatives of progress bars, which could be invoked through java method** i.e progress bar starts on file upload action and ends when the upload is done.

I am a beginner. Any help would be appreciated! Thankyou!

Comment: Have you tried doing `onclick="NProgress.start();"` which for all buttons including NONAjax buttons starts as soon as they click the button.  And you if you change your actionListener to an `action="#{uploadCntrl.uploadZip()}"` it should reload the whole page and thus killing the NProgress bar.  give it a try...